# Nested JSON data source with DataTables

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json, datatables

I have JSON data source with nested obvar

```
jsonData = {
    "block":[
    {"name": "Block 1. Social Work",
    "subblock": [{
            "name": "Block 1.1. Student Org (SO)",
                "paragraph": [
                {
                  "name": "Head of SO",
                  "score": "10,00"
                }, {
                  "name": "Head of Group" ,
                  "score": "9, 00 "
                }]

    }]
    }]
    };
```

Wher block.name = table caption, subblock.name =

```
    var subbl_content=document.createElement("th");
        subbl_content.colSpan=4;
        subbl_content.innerHTML=jsonData[0].block[0].subblock[0].name;
```

paragraph = table content. I try to place it to DataTable in the following way

```
$(document).ready(function() {
.....
$('#example').DataTable( 
    {
      data: jsonData,
        columns: [
            { data: 'block[0].subblock[0].paragraph[0].name' },
            { data: 'block[0].subblock[0].paragraph[0].score' }
        ]

    });

}) ;
```

It would seem that must work but as a result i have in one Cell next value **Head of SOiHead of Group**. But when i some change data like

```
$('#example').DataTable( 
    {
      data: jsonData.block[0].subblock[0].paragraph,
        columns: [
            { data: 'name' },
            { data: 'score' }
        ]

    });
```

All works. Is it normal or are there other methods of solution?

Comment: Can you modify the JSON structure? Is there always only one `block` and only one `sunblock` in the JSON? If so, some of that array nesting is unnecessary.

Comment: JSON can have only one block (cause table have only one caption) , many subblock. Subblock can have many paragraph( that is, rows between subblocks)

Comment: In that case I would not even have "block", just start with the block's `name`.  I.E. `name` and `sunblock` are not wrapped together in an array. And `sunblock` is an array - so rename it `sunblocks` (the plural). Then your code will be that much simpler overall.

Comment: Such this ?
jsonData = {
    "name": "Block 1. Social Work",
    "subblock": {
            "name": "Block 1.1. Student Org (SO)",
                "paragraph": [
                {
                  "name": "Head of SO",
                  "score": "10,00"
                }, {
                  "name": "Head of Group" ,
                  "score": "9, 00 "
                }]
                 }
    
    };

Comment: ... `"subblocks" : [ {"name" : "whoMe" ...}, { "name" : "thatTune", ... } ]`

Comment: emmm,but how about paragraph?